# Listar nomes duplicados no MySQL para alteração

Tags: mysql

Preciso listar todos os nomes duplicados em uma determinada tabela e não estou conseguindo, o que tenho até o momento é isso:

```
SELECT nome, foto, ativo, count(nome) FROM comColaborador GROUP BY nome HAVING count( nome ) > 1
```

Mas esse script só me mostra um registro e a sua contagem indicando duplicidade, preciso listar os mesmos.

O tentei também foi isso:

```
SELECT nome, foto, ativo FROM comColaborador WHERE nome LIKE "%ABRAAO BRANDAO MORAES%"
```

Mas fica oneroso demais ter que pesquisar informando os nomes que desejo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta fazer com uma subquery assim:

```
SELECT nome, foto, ativo FROM comColaborador 
WHERE id in(
    SELECT id FROM comColaborador GROUP BY nome HAVING count( nome ) > 1
)
```

Não tive tempo de testar aqui mas acho que da certo

Comment: Fiz um teste, mas não pegou os duplicados, mas valeu pela ajuda @Wagner Soares.

Comment: Estranho, era pra ter dado certo kkkkk

Comment: Olá @Wagner Soares, esse "id" é o de minha tabela?
Ficou assim:

SELECT nome, foto, ativo FROM comColaborador
WHERE idColaborador in (
    SELECT idColaborador FROM comColaborador GROUP BY nome HAVING count( nome ) > 1 order by nome asc
)

Comment: Isto, não deu certo assim?

Comment: So uma observação, pra ordenar o resultado final order by deve ficar apos o ")" assim:
 SELECT nome, foto, ativo FROM comColaborador WHERE idColaborador in ( SELECT idColaborador FROM comColaborador GROUP BY nome HAVING count( nome ) > 1 ) order by nome asc